# How to iterate through csv rows, apply a function to those values and append to new column?

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script which calculates tree heights based off distance and angle from the ground, however, despite the script running with no errors my heights column is left empty. Also, I dont want to be using pandas and I would like to keep to the 'with open' method if possible, before anyone suggests going about it a different way. Any help would be great thanks. It seems that the whole script runs fine and does everything i need it to until the "for row in csvread:" block.
This is my current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Import any modules needed
import sys
import csv
import math
import os
import itertools

# Extract command line arguments, remove file extension and attach to output_filename
input_filename1 = sys.argv[1]
input_filename2 = os.path.splitext(input_filename1)[0]
filenames = (input_filename2, "treeheights.csv")
output_filename = "".join(filenames)

def TreeHeight(degrees, distance):
    """
    This function calculates the heights of trees given distance 
    of each tree from its base and angle to its top, using the 
    trigonometric formula.
    """
    radians = math.radians(degrees)
    height = distance * math.tan(radians)
    print("Tree height is:", height)
    
    return height

def main(argv):
    with open(input_filename1, 'r') as f:
        with open(output_filename, 'w') as g:
    
            csvread = csv.reader(f)
            print(csvread)
            csvwrite = csv.writer(g)
    
            header = csvread.__next__()
            header.append("Height.m")
            csvwrite.writerow(header)
    
            # Populating the output csv with the input data
            csvwrite.writerows(itertools.islice(csvread, 0, 121))
    
            for row in csvread:
                height = TreeHeight(csvread[:,2], csvread[:,1])
                row.append(height)
                csvwrite.writerow(row)
return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    status = main(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(status)
```

Comment: Welcome! Great looking code so far. I think I've spotted at least one small issue, but also see a maybe-larger issue around misunderstanding how CSV **reader** and **writer** work.

Comment: pandas can both handle the reading and writing to CSV for you, it will make the code more compact and readible. Unless you have strong reasons do it yourself, let pandas take care of reading/writing to CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think you're mostly there, but are a little confused on reading/writing *rows*:

```py
# Populating the output csv with the input data
csvwrite.writerows(itertools.islice(csvread, 0, 121))

for row in csvread:
    height = TreeHeight(csvread[:,2], csvread[:,1])
    row.append(height)
    csvwrite.writerow(row)
```

It looks like your reading rows 1 through 121 and writing them to your new file.  *Then*, you're trying to iterate over your CSV reader in a second pass, compute the height, and then tack that computed value on to the end of the row, and also write to your CSV in a complete second pass.

If that's true, then you need to understand that CSV **reader** and **writer** are not designed to work "left-to-right" like that: read-write these columns, then read-write these columns... nope.

They both work "top-down", processing rows.

I propose, to get this working: iterate every row in one loop, and for every row:

- read the values you need from `row` to compute the height
- get the computed height
- add the new computed to the original
- write

```py
...

header = next(csvread)
header.append("Height.m")
csvwrite.writerow(header)

for row in csvread:
    degrees = float(row[1])   # second column for degrees?
    distance = float(row[0])  # first column for distance?
    height = TreeHeight(degrees, distance)
    row.append(height)
    csvwrite.writerow(row)
```

Some changes I made:

- I replaced `header = csvread.__next__()` with `header = next(csvread)`.  Calling things that start with `_` or `__` is generally discouraged, at least in the standard library.  `next(<iterator>)` is the built-in function that allows you to properly and safely advance through `<iterator>`.
- Added `float()` conversion to textual values as read from CSV

Also, as far as I can tell, the `,2`/`,1` is incorrect syntax for subscripting/slice notation.  You didn't get any errors because the reader was already done/exhausted from the `islice()` call, so your program never actually stepped into the `for row in csvread:` loop.

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you for taking the time to explain, I'm an R user and new to python so I try to go about python in the same way I would R and python normally gets very angry at me.

Comment: Great! I was wondering if you were thinking in terms of another API/Language. :) Cheers.